# how to enable scroll bar with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I googled and they said I need highstock module, but I don't want use
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>`
(I don't know where to import it..)
is there a react way to import highstock module?

I have tried this:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import HC_more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
    <HighchartsReact
                    allowChartUpdate={true}
                    updateArgs={[true, true, true]}
                    hicharts={Highcharts}
                    options={chartConfig}
                    ref={chart}
                ></HighchartsReact>

and the chartConfig:

const chartOption = {
    chart: {
      type: "bar"
    },
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true
    },
    xAxis: {
      scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
      },
      min: 0,
      max: 2,
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Browsers",
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: chartData
      }
    ]
  };
```

it just not work for me . here is the demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-highchart-jjzjx118

Comment: Your title and your question is entirely different, what are you really looking for

Comment: sorry, I am looking for the way enable scroll bar with react-highcharts, I have tried some way but not work. I'm not sure the problem is about import highstock module or else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already imported Highcharts here:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
```

You should be able to enable the `scrollbar` in this way:

```
scrollbar: {
  enabled: true
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-2dwcc

Comment: thanks for your answer, your demo works fine, but it's not work in my demo :https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-highchart-jjzjx118 can you take a look at it? I think the config is totally same

Comment: Hi @jjzjx118_2, You need to change: `<HighchartsReact hicharts={Highcharts} options={option} />` to `<HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={option} />`

Comment: thanks you ... I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake..